# PrintWriter not printing out complete string

Tags: java, string, io, filewriter, printwriter

I have the following code

```
FileWriter F = new FileWriter("out.txt");
PrintWriter H = new PrintWriter(F);
H.print(split[split.length - 2]);
H.print("END");
```

When I examine the txt however, the last text is NOT 'END', but part of a word in the string. It is "repa"

When I do this

```
FileWriter F = new FileWriter("out.txt");
PrintWriter H = new PrintWriter(F);
System.out.print(split[split.length - 2]);
```

The last bit of text I get is the number '49' - this is correct.

It appears that the PrintWriter is not fully writing out the string. However, when I do this

```
FileWriter F = new FileWriter("out.txt");
PrintWriter H = new PrintWriter(F);
H.print(split[split.length - 2]);
H.println(pdfInText)://Another string
H.print("END");
```

The 'original' text now actually finishes - what is this?

Comment: Nobody? I have no clue what is going on here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you close the `PrintWriter`? From its javadoc

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println() methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. The println() methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

If you do close the `PrintWriter` (and not the FileWriter!) try a `flush()` after printing, to force that.